# 1995 Chrysler Concorde that only started by WIGGLING the wheel - NOW does not start at all!

Tags: starting, ignition

I have a 1995 Chrysler Concorde - a little over 72,000 miles. I'm 77 years old and want to keep this car. For 2 or 3 months, the car had only been starting if I lined up the steering wheel exactly right: I had lines drawn to match the steering wheel to the column. Now with the same lineup, it still cranks but won't start!  I'd really hate to have to get rid of this car, but I can't figure out why this is happening.

It has a new battery, and I replaced the ignition switch a month ago, but the condition stayed the same.

Answer (score 0):

Good car, I had a 96 Chrysler Concorde, 7 years ago. It’s an old car, it matters if it was stored in a garage or outside.

First, check the wiring. For loose connections. The gearshift is on the right side of the steering column, and someone was in there at some point to replace the switch, it is likely that a wire was disconnected and it would only ever reconnect when you held it in place by the wheel position. 
Imagine having to hold the battery in the remote to turn on the tv. 
It might me as easy as removing the horn cover and taping a wire.

Comment: Will have this done. and inform as to what fixed this car. My gearshift is in the middle, between the seats. What switch do you think was replaced. Car  to be fixed this week. I will inform later -what was the real cause of this trouble- so maybe it can help somebody else.

Comment: Car starts right away NOW.

Car had new starter put in. Mechanic said it worked for a while, but then could not start it. 

He put in ANOTHER ignition starter relay (RY116T)  Ah...like I had put in a NEW one weeks before.

Makes me wonder if the starter maybe was okay. Like- is their something that shorts that

ignition starter relay??? In case it won't start in future. Does anybody out there have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds suspiciously like it could be the 'clockspring' in the steering column of the vehicle, or an open in the steering column wiring harness.  It should not be too difficult for a mechanic to find, I'd strongly recommend taking it in to your friendly local neighborhood mechanic.

Comment: Hope to have car fixed in a few days. Will bear all info in mind that you gave me. Will later notify on this site -what really was the problem- just so somebody else may be helped.